# Validate the string entered is of mm/dd/yyyy format

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a datepicker control for the users to pick the date, however, they also need to enter the date manually. As such, I need to validate the date entered by the user in the textbox.

Below is the code that I am using to validate

```
 DateTime Test;
       if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strtdate)))
       {
           bool valid = DateTime.TryParseExact(strtdate, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out Test);
       }
```

The date entered by the user is 6/29/2011, however it gives the bool valid value as false though it is correct.

What am I missing here? Please let me know, its urgent.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the following format "M/dd/yyyy"

M is for 1..12

Answer (score 2):

It's urgent....well you said to let you know. ;-)

I'm assuming TryParseExact fails because there is only one digit for the month and not two as specified in the format field.  If you use TryParse instead it should work fine.